# Intersection of a vector linestring and underlying DEM

Tags: postgis, dem, intersection

Following is an screen-shot where ASTER DEM raster layer has been overlaid by a road linestring vector layer. I want to extract those DEM pixels which are lying exactly beneath the linestrings. I want to assign the corresponding elevation values to each and every linestring. Which PostGIS function should be used or any other approach? PostGIS `ST_Intersection` function for Raster Layers is not useful.
[image]

Comment: What should happen if a polyline spans multiple cells?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function [ST_DumpAsPolygons](http://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_DumpAsPolygons.html):

```
SELECT 
    (ST_DumpAsPolygons(rast)).*
FROM road_linestring_table,dem 
    WHERE ST_Intersects(rast, geom);
```

Afterwards you can rasterize the result.